# Jasmine Object #<Scope> has no method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I keep getting the error: `Object <Scope> has no method` and I have looked around and tried everything.

Here is my jasmine:

```
var scope, service1, service2;
var EmployeeService_mock = function(){
        var obj = {
            visibleEmployees : [],
            selectedEmployee : null
        };
        obj.setSelectedEmployee = function (emp) {
            obj.selectedEmployee = emp;
        };
        return obj;
    };
    var EmpTreeNavigationService_mock = function(){

    };

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        service1 = new EmployeeService_mock();
        service2 = new EmpTreeNavigationService_mock();
        $controller('EmployeesCtrl',
            {
                $scope: scope,
                EmployeeService: service1,
                EmpTreeNavigationService: service2
            }
        );
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should test', function(){
        expect(scope.isSelectedEmployee(emp1)).toBeTruthy();   
    });
```

And here is my .js

```
$scope.isSelectedEmployee = function (emp) {
    return true;
};
```

I cannot seem to figure this out. I have double checked my spelling, looked at other examples, and this should be working.

Comment: What method does it not have? The error message seems like the error message might have been truncated.

Comment: Sorry @mfollet, it does not have the method, isSelectedEmployee.  I left that part out because that changes based on what method I call.  It throws the error for all scope.blah calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most possible problem I can see is that you forgot to load your module in your tests. Something like this:

```
beforeEach(module('yourModule'));
```

Take a look at this [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EA8wWq4HqnpHGxtLFQNx?p=preview) and [not working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0khEk8jQ8LRSvI3cXS4l?p=preview) (which has the exact same problem)